# How to install Honeyd in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware. I have to test the working of honeyd. Suggest me the exact step by step installation process of Honeyd in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install honeyd
```

Comment: fails: `E: Package 'honeyd' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: I am using `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Answer (score 1):

From experience I have found that the documentation isn't exactly self explanatory.  I wrote this article a while ago:

https://www.felixrr.pro/archives/273/how-to-install-honeyd-on-ubuntu-12-04-1

I hope that addresses your question better.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in Ubuntu or honeyd that fails the installation via compile and make the honeyd codes, but I finally found a simple way to install honeyd.

Open up the following page and then download your 32bit or 64bit version of honeyd. Now it's expected you'll have a `deb` file, so you can open this file by *Ubuntu software center* and inside the USC click on install button. Alternatively you can install that `deb` file by the Debian Package Manager (dpkg).

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/honeyd