# Install honeyd in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: error-handling

```
wget http://www.honeyd.org/uploads/honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz

--2018-01-04 02:20:07--  http://www.honeyd.org/uploads/honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz
Resolving www.honeyd.org (www.honeyd.org)... 207.158.15.70
Connecting to www.honeyd.org (www.honeyd.org)[207.158.15.70]:80... connected.
HTTP sent request, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 915465 (894K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: “honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz”

honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz  100%[===================>] 14,01K  30,8KB/s     

2018-01-04 02:24:53 (54.6 KB/s) - ‘honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz’ saved [915465/915465]



bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/25962/692175

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the following command in order the extract the files:

```
tar -zxvf honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz
```

And about the title of your question, this link might be useful: [How to install Honeyd in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159831/how-to-install-honeyd-in-ubuntu)

Hope this helps.